# What is the appropriate Stack Exchange site for a question related to GNOME 3?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the appropriate Stack Exchange site for a question related to GNOME 3?

It's specific to the "reset" program for the "terminal" application.

Comment: I would use [unix.se]

Answer (score 6):

Both [Super User](https://superuser.com) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) are suitable, depending on what your question focuses on.

If your question focuses more on the usage of the program, it fits both, but please don't cross-post. If your question focuses more on the internals of the program and/or how it works with a Unix or Linux environment, it may fit better on U&L.